# Función pasandoPorI. Ciclo for JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo que resolver la siguiente consigna:

Escribí una función llamada `pasandoPorI` (la última letra es una `i` latina mayúscula) que muestre por consola *"acá `i` tiene el valor de `x`"* donde `x` va a ser el valor de la variable `i` en cada iteración, por cada valor que va tomando `i` desde `0` hasta el número `4` inclusive.

Esto fue lo que hice, pero me da error:

```js
function pasandoPorI() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(pasandoPorI("acá i tiene el valor de" + i));
  }
}
```

Este es el error que obtengo:

```
La función pasandoPorI debe iterar un total de 5 veces
La función pasandoPorI debe imprimir como va cambiando el valor de i en el ciclo, en éste caso debe imprimir 'acá i tiene el valor de ...' 0,1,2,3 y 4 según corresponda.
```

Comment: Hola @glbinaghi. No pierdas de vista esta lectura => [¿Cómo escribo un buen título?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4774/c%c3%b3mo-escribo-un-buen-t%c3%adtulo). Te será de mucha ayuda para describir el problema y captar la atención de las personas con la ayuda de un título más adecuado. En caso de que no estés de acuerdo con el título lo puedes cambiar a uno más descriptivo, pero que no incluya la palabra **ejercicios**,

Answer (score 2):

Cambia esta línea:

```js
console.log(pasandoPorI("acá i tiene el valor de" + i));
```

Por esta otra:

```js
console.log("acá i tiene el valor de " + i);
```

Y llamas la función desde afuera así:

```js
pasandoPorI();
```

Comment: Gracias. Ya lo solucioné

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo muy bien por qué en `console.log` haces otra llamada a `pasandoPorI()`. Yo lo haría de la siguiente manera:

```
function pasandoPorI() { 
    for ( let i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ){
        console.log ("acá i tiene el valor de " + i); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Corregí la respuesta. Sobraba un paréntesis en console.log. Prueba ahora a ver.

Comment: Bue. Ahí ya lo corregí. Yo lo habia puesto así, sin el () que sobraba. No me daba. Pero ahora si me dió bien. En fin, no se cuál era el problema jajaja mil gracias por todo!!!